# Find if a sentence is completely capital?

Tags: python

I have a variable, and i want to check if it is completely in capital.

```
loc = "SAN JOSE"
```

How can i check if the entire phrase in capital. I know how to check if the individual letter is capital. It can have as many words.

```
loc[0].isupper()
>>True
```

Comment: @kojiro that's not how `all` works - maybe you mean `all(map(str.isupper, loc))` and probably `loc and` in front of it to cater for empty strings

Answer (score 5):

Python doesn't differentiate between strings and characters. Just call the same method on the whole string:

```
loc.isupper()
```

Comment: +1 though technically Python does *sometimes* distinguish strings of length 1. For example, `ord()`.

Comment: Good point. As a general rule of thumb they will be the same though.

Comment: It's actually the `ord` function that checks to see if it's a single-length string (or byte array). The source, if you're interested, is here: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/66398e1307f4/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1468

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> "SAN JOSE".isupper()
True
>>> "SAN jOSE".isupper()
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the `isupper` function, like `loc.isupper()`. Punctuation does not affect this. Let me demonstrate:

```
>>> a = "CHEESE-CAKE"
>>> a.isupper()
True
>>> b = "SAN JOSE"
>>> b.isupper()
True
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isupper#str.isupper) for it. `isupper` only takes alphabetic characters into consideration. For example:

```
>>> a = "CHEESE123123CAKE"
>>> a.isupper()
True
```

The following example serves no other purpose but to have some fun:

```
>>> ">-----+>A<+------<".isupper()
True
>>> ":P".isupper()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loc = "Your Text"

print upper_text == loc.upper()
```

or you can check with the `ASCII` value

Answer (score 0):

```
loc = "SAN JOSE"
if loc == loc.upper():
    print 'All Upper'
```